# Find distinct leading monomials with respect to monomial orders

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the polynomial $f=2xy^2-xy+x^3$.
Now find two monomial orders for which the leading monomials are different.

If I'm correct $lm(f)_{<lex}=x^3$ (lexicographic order) and I think it's the same for the graded lexicographic order?

Thanks for any examples!